# Expectation of convex function

Tags: probability-theory, convex-analysis, expectation

This is my problem:
Let $F(x, W)$ be a function of $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and a random variable $W$  also taking values in $\mathbb{R}$. Now define $f(x)$ such that

$ f(x) = \int_{\Omega} F(x, W(\omega)) \mathbb{P}(d\omega)$.

How do I prove that F(x,W) is convex in x for any realization of W if f(x) is convex in x???

If $\Omega$ is finite then I can easily prove it by using the fact that the sum of convex functions is convex. If $\Omega$ is finite then
$ f(x) = \sum_{\Omega} F(x, W(\omega)) \mathbb{P}(\omega)$. If $f(w)$ is convex, then $F(x,W(\omega))$ is also convex for sample paths with non-zero probability. Otherwise, we have a contradiction (convex + concave = not convex.)

But I'm not sure how to prove that it holds when $\Omega$ is not finite e.g. Gaussian distribution. How do I extend my argument to the more general case???

Edit:
Let $\mathbb{E}(W)$ be the expected value of $W$.

How about prove $F(x,\mathbb{E}(W))$ is convex in x if f(x) is convex in x??? Is it incorrect????

Comment: The implication you ask to prove does not hold. The reverse implication, on the other hand, does hold.

Comment: Thank you Did. If you are not too busy, can you provide me with the intuition or logic, please? I'm struggling to understand what and why it changes when we move to settings where $\Omega$ is not finite.

Comment: Things do not change when Omega is infinite. (From the discussion below, anyway, it seems you really are trying to prove the implication which does not hold...)

Comment: Sorry. I've added more detail. My understanding is that if $\Omega$ is finite, then $F(x,W(\omega))$ is convex on paths with non-zero probability. Can I get a similar result when $\Omega$ is not finite?

Comment: As I said, whether $\Omega$ is finite or infinite, the convexity of $f$ cannot imply any convexity of the functions $F(\cdot,w)$.

Answer (score 0):

It's true, of course.  You need to check inequalities like $pf(x)+qf(y)\ge f(px+qy)$.  (For all $x$ and $y$,  and so on.) These follow by observing that for each $W$, $$pF(x,W)+qF(y,W))-F(px+qy,W)$$ is nonnegative.  Now you integrate with respect to $W$: the expectation of a nonnegative random variable is nonnegative.

Comment: I think you are proving the opposite direction of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You are right: careless of me.  But if $EW=0$ and $F(x,W)=x^2 W$, your $f$ is convex and your $F$ is not always so.

Comment: Thanks. Hahahaha. I'm feel so embarased. Thanks.